# jQuery content loading into div on loaded page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a working script to a degree. The problem is the last content does not load into the targeted div area, but it load into the whole page.

First page the is the landing page and is fine:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a class="dashnav" href="content/company.html">Company</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dashnav" href="content/buyer.html">Buyer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dashnav" href="content/settings.html">Settings</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

This is the jQuery. It loads the menus fine, but does not load the last content into the dashcontent div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // select where the content is to go and what content is be loaded

    $('#content').load($('.dashnav:first').attr('href'));

    //click button from first dashnav
    $('.dashnav').click(function () {

        //What Link has been clicked
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        //load content from that link
        $('#content').load(href, function () {

            //once the content is loaded
            $('#dashcontent').load($('.companynav:first').attr('href'));

            //click on link from newly loaded page
            $('.companynav').click(function () {

                //What Link has been clicked
                var href = $(this).attr('href');

                //load that content
                $('#dashcontent').load(href);

            });

        });

        return false; //stops the page redirect

    });

});
```

The second page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills companynav">
    <li><a href="content/dashboard/basic.html">Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="content/dashboard/factory.html">Factory</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="content/dashboard/company_bio.html">Company Bio</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div id="dashcontent"></div>
</div>
```

The final result that should load the basic.html into the dashcontent area but it does not:

```
<h1>Basic Profile</h1>
<p>Edit your Company profile</p>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try adding some breakpoints or use console.log() to see which callback are being run. From what I understand `$('#dashcontent').load($('.companynav:first').attr('href'));` fails or is never run. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using jQuery's `.on()` method with event delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Also, I would clean up the code if I were you to have less callbacks and instead use promises.

For your immediate question though, it looks like this:

```
$('#dashcontent').load($('.companynav:first').attr('href'));
```

should be

```
$('#dashcontent').load($('.companynav a:first').attr('href'));
```

Preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/SJzK17sw5YVLrQvuI7Gb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false also in your second (nested) click handler, on .companynav :

```
....
//click on link from newly loaded page
$('.companynav').click(function(){

    //What Link has been clicked
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); 

    //load that content
    $('#dashcontent').load(href);

  return false;

 });
....
```